# Different nameserver and glue record

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, domain-registrar, glue-record

I have a domain called domain.com (already working and in production) and that domain is already using ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com as nameservers.

Now I have created new Authoritative DNS server (ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com) and I want to migrate the domain.com to it. So that NS for domain.com will become ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com

Now, the issue here is there is no glue record created for ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com.

Does creating the glue record for ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com will disturb the existing domain.com DNS service? ( for which the current NS are ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com)

Answer (score 0):

The glue records must appear in the parent zone (`.com`) simultaneously with change of delegation records. This is ususally the case; these TLDs usually get updates in batches and all your updates will be in a single batch.

You must configure new servers in advance, and let old servers to continue the service after the update was done at least the until the longest TTL expires, so everybody who ever could have cashed data will get answer. During this transition period it is not recommended to update the zone data.

If everything is done so, nothing would be disturbed.

Currently `.com` zone contains for you:

```
domain.com. NS ns1.example.com.
domain.com. NS ns2.example.com.
```

It will contain after update:

```
domain.com. NS ns1.domain.com.
domain.com. NS ns2.domain.com.
ns1.domain.com. A 1.2.3.4
ns2.domain.com. A 5.6.7.8
```

latter two are the glue records and again, they'll appear in the zone together with new delegations.

Comment: so, you mean to say that I can create the glue for ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com while domain.com is still served using ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com?

Comment: Glue exists *in the parent zone*. They'll be created when you go into your registrar control panel and update delegation from `ns1.example.com` to `ns1.domain.com`, same for ns2. You'll be forced to enter IP address together with server name, that's exactly for registrar to be able to create necessary glue records.